# how to set cursor background transparent for EditText Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm having this issue when I touch an EditText for changing text on Android:

[image]
A white frame appears around the red cursor, and I need it to be transparent for showing properly the line of the EditText. How do I change this?

code:

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/login_user_name_text"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:maxLength="60"
            />
```

---

**EDIT:** I could fix it by replacing:

```
<item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
```

for

```
<item name="android:background">@color/transparent</item>
```

in styles.xml

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    </style>
```

[image]

Comment: Does the image for the cursor have a white background itself? You might have to edit the image.

Comment: what's the property name or where do you edit that??? I'm not setting any value for cursor image on my EditText, gonna upload my code as well

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for the late,
I think you have 
`<item name="android:popupBackground">@color/white</item>` in your style from v21, 
just remove it, It may solve your problem

Answer (score 3):

Another solution, which works if you are having this problem with an EditText *inside a SearchView while using a Toolbar*.

1. In your activity XML add the `android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"` attribute to Toolbar:

   ```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   android:id="@+id/toolbar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
   app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
   android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
   android:elevation="2dp" />
   ```
2. Then, *remove* `<item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>` from your `ToolBarStyle` in styles.xml.

Hope this helps someone else looking for a solution for this particular case.

Comment: could the downvoter please explain the downvote? thanks!

Comment: Had a similar issue. In my case though, the problem was simply fixed by removing `android:background="#FFFFFF"` from the Toolbar layout.
You pointed me to the issue though, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

better using `@android:color/transparent` instead of `null` on the `android:textCursorDrawable="@android:color/transparent"`

Answer (score 1):

Setting `android:background` to transparent didn't do the trick for me.

In my case I set a theme to the parent viewgroup that defined the background to be a certain color, so it was applied to the EditText as well. Making sure that the background was just set for the parent solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your EditText XML instead of `null`;

```
android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/colorcursor"
```

Then, create a file called colorcursor.xml inside your drawable folder;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <size android:width="3dp" />
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"  />
</shape>
```