# Android - Styling cursor in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, cursor, text-styling

I have an edittext box and a weird thing happens when a text is typed. The cursor pin has a big white border that clips the views under it. How do I style this cursor to have transparent background? I don't want a custom cursor, just have this one's background set.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set cursor background transparent for EditText Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41232652/how-to-set-cursor-background-transparent-for-edittext-android)

Answer (score 1):

Found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41232652/how-to-set-cursor-background-transparent-for-edittext-android). Removing `android:background` did the trick in this case. This is quite surprising (and possibly an Android bug). What if we *do* need to set the background anyhow?